# What is diffence between two closures?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures

I am using my js files like:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('app.someModule')
    .config(config);
    function config(someDependency){
    //some configuration
    }
    config.$inject=['someDependency'];
})();
```

However I saw when i using closures some people injects the angular object itself the closure. Something like:

```
(function(angular){/*whatever logic*/})(angular);
```

Which one is a better usage or Are there any difference between two usage?

So I dont add global angular variable as always that don't cause any trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between two immediately executed functions (IIFE) is that in the second case you invoke function with one parameter `angular`. The benefit it can give is slightly improved performance as there is no need for Javascript engine to look up for a variable in global scope, as the `angular` object is available in local closure scope as a reference passed with function invocation (but of course it still points to the same Angular object, defined in global scope).